# Youtube Related Videos using Youtube V3 API

Tags: youtube-api

I need the API URL for Youtube Related Videos using the Youtube V3 API. 
But I couldn't find the direct API call, like it is in Version 2. Did I miss something?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Are you trying to find videos related to a video?

You can use [**search->list**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call for this with specifying the "[**relatedToVideoId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId)"

And for anyone looking for a coded example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=5rOiW_xY-kc&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: That worked. Didn't check it before. Thanks for that. Appreciate it.

Comment: can you suggest me that how to get Related keywords suggestion by using API V3?

Comment: Hi, can you give me suggested/related videos only from particular channel

Answer (score 0):

Just an Update to this answer -> Youtube don't provide this api from 7th AUG 2023.

Comment: Hi, can you expand with a link?

Comment: well, I just looked at the api reference for search and this option was not there anymore. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters

Comment: here a link @pierpy https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_06_12_2023