# YouTube IFRAME player: setting the next video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

How can I set the video ID which should follow automatically after the current video has ended?

`player.loadVideoById()` and `player.cueVideoById` immediately switch to the video in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below `code` to achieve the same -

```
<html>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var ScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, ScriptTag);

var player; 
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {                      
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId : 'YtF6p_w-cSc',                 
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }      
        });
      }        
       function onPlayerReady(event) {                                        
       event.target.playVideo();
      }       
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {   
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {   
           player.loadVideoById ('4MJRS-cLozU');
        }       
      }

</script>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaqb9ffL/)

As per the above code `youtube` will automatically play `first video` i.e.`YtF6p_w-cSc` and when the current video ends it will automatically play the `next video` i.e. `4MJRS-cLozU`. Hope this will help you and you are looking for the same. Also, please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks..!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I implemented because I haven't found anything in the YT-API itself. Great answer!

Comment: @PPB how can i start automatically on next video. not a static. if you can see here my exampe as well.



https://www.ighomall.com/index.php?route=tmdvideo/tmdallvideo&videocategory_id=1

Comment: @MujahidBhoraniya I did not get your question, could you please explain a bit more? And in the example video it gets stopped once the video is ended.

Comment: @PPB I already send my website URL. 

This is a link from youtube. When video play to end it loads all related youtube videos. When you click on them it takes you out of the site to the youtube website.
Can we make the video stop 1second to the end and automatically move to our next video

Comment: @PPB. still not working. you can set it via HTML Elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052074/autoplay-next-video-in-embedded-youtube-player#:~:text=There%20is%20an%20Autoplay%20feature,the%20web%20page%20is%20loaded.