# A youtube api with sub videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hey guy's I am trying to find or make an youtube api.

I have searched on : https://developers.google.com/youtube/
Because I am a beginner I coulnd figure out how to make it.
searched and tried some exaples. The most what I can find is 
iframe of 1 video

Comment: This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725950/youtube-related-videos-using-youtube-v3-api) looks similar to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question couple years ago .

Here in this [link you will find answer to your question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdqsiFw74Jk&t=)

and a little bit help from the [youtube api link](http://%20https://developers.google.com/youtube/)
just to understand better.

Comment: I skipped to the last part to write it over and it worked 

THNX a lot THANK YOU

I would never thought that the answer was in youtube -_-''