# How to get relatedVideos based on videoId from youtube API v3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a YouTube clone from YouTube API v3, whereas I need to related videos list based on the current playing video's videoId.

```
async function getApiData(videoId) {
    const res = await apiRequest('/search', {
        params: {
            part: 'snippet',
            videoCategoryId: videoId, // relatedToVideoId : videoId
            maximumResult: 10,
            type: 'video'   
        }
    })
    console.log("res", res)
    return res;
}
```

In the params, I have passed videoCategoryId/relatedToVideoId, in different requests.
but it sends an error message.

What would be the correct way to get a related video list from the YouTube API based on the videoId?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I think to retrieve related videos based on a given `videoId` using the YouTube API v3, you should use the `relatedToVideoId` parameter instead of `videoCategoryId`.

The `videoCategoryId` parameter is used for filtering videos by category, not for retrieving related videos.

I add sample code below:

```
async function getRelatedVideos(videoId) {
    const res = await apiRequest('/search', {
        params: {
            part: 'snippet',
            type: 'video',
            relatedToVideoId: videoId,
            maxResults: 10, // It's 'maxResults', not 'maximumResult'
        }
    });

    console.log("res", res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Adrid, still getting the same error **Request contains an invalid argument.**, I have replaced the params as per your suggestion. 

Has YouTube changed the methodology to get related videos, I haven't seen relatedVideos docs in this link -  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list ?

Please help I am not a very experienced developer.

Comment: @anilraj that feature has been removed from the API, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77525636 (I'm curious why they'd remove such a useful thing.)